# How feasible is it to power your home with a bicycle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, everyday-life, power, home-experiment

[This article](http://www.trueactivist.com/60-minutes-on-this-bicycle-can-power-your-home-for-24-hours/) claims "60 Minutes On This Bicycle Can Power Your Home For 24 Hours!" How feasible is this claim? Sounds great - but the skeptic in me says "yeah, right."

Hope this is an acceptable forum to post this question - if not, can someone please migrate it?

Comment: I think I've seen this design before...I remember my teacher (this was 7th grade intro to engineering) saying this was an incredible guy, and a very smart idea. The fact he said it reduces the likelihood of it being wrong in my mind, but of course he could've been.

Comment: Depends on what kind of home. If you're athletic, you might be able output a few hundred watts for one hour. That's certainly enough to power, say, a small lamp and a laptop/phone charger for most of the day. It's not enough to power an average Western home, not even close.

Comment: @heather: That's a wonderful data point for why one should never trust a teacher, especially not the 7th grade science teacher. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne: I honestly don't remember it that well...he could've been talking about it in terms of third-world countries, sort of as discussed below in hdhondt's answer. Besides, he was a pretty smart teacher. And finally...never trust a teacher? That sounds like a bad idea to me. Except, you know, in certain cases. But generally, it sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: It's all about the power demands of you home, now isn't it? A few people have been living off the grid this way on for decades. It used to require a big sacrifice in terms of what automation you used. In these more efficient days careful design can make it a much smaller sacrifice.

Comment: @heather: But even though you say that you don't remember it well, you were willing to reproduce that "information". That's a very common psychological phenomenon. What we learn as children sticks with us, even if it's flat out wrong. It would, by the way, also be wrong for third world countries. What people need to develop their countries are tractors to plow their fields, just like we did. They don't need to go "green" on energy, they already are at the subsistence level, or below, as far as energy use is conserved.

Comment: Engineers sometimes make a distinction between "horsepower" and "shaft horsepower" where the latter is what comes out on the shaft and can actually be used for work as opposed to the former which is a measure of some energy transfer inside the machine that may or may not directly track the machine's ability to do work. This difference shows up in comparing tractor-trailer engines and consumer automobile engines. It also shows up in the distinction between what your treadmill will tell you're burning and what you can actually use to charge a battery pack.

Comment: [Hire retired cyclist Indurain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_Indurain#Physical_prowess)

Comment: This is an 'exercise' type of problem (no pun intended).  You are asking us to do some research and make a calculation which you have not attempted to do yourself.  That is contrary to the policy of this site : see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 8):

A human can produce about [100 W power](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2003/WeiLiangMok.shtml) continuously. That is equivalent to a couple of lightbulbs. So, while pedalling continuously you can keep one room reasonably lit.

In one hour, that means you can generate a total energy of 0.1 kWh. A top athlete will be able to do better, so let's say it is possible to generate 0.2 kWh in 1 hour. That is still nowhere near enough to provide power for lighting, refrigerator, heating/cooling, etc that are required around the home. An average American home uses about [30 kWh per day](http://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.cfm?id=97&t=3), so you would need 150 people or 75 athletes pedalling 1 hour to generate power for a day.

Of course, for a 3rd world country, where all the electricity used is to power a mobile phone and a single lightbulb at night, this may well be a useful solution. On the other hand, a couple of solar cells will probably not cost any more, and they charge batteries while the owner can do other work.

Comment: Keep in mind that home lighting today can quite economically be LEDs rather than incandescent, so the power demand for lighting is down by about an order of magnitude.

Comment: This is about right. You would have a difficult time powering your air conditioner during the summer. The only way this sort of human power could be feasibly employed and power a home to current levels is with slavery. You would need slaves to work the bicycle generators, and a lot of them. They would probably rebel against you, as seen with the end of Apartheid South Africa.

Comment: But @dmckee is also right about LEDs. I'd overlooked those and 0.1kWh will power a 10W LED for 10 hours, or 3 of them for a whole evening.

Comment: Also note that I think that 100W figure you're quoting may be the total energy output  by a human - and, if so, most of this will simply be heat to uphold body temperature. If it's 20C outside and your human is at 37C, the Carnot efficiency would $1 - (293/310)\approx 5\%$. Not a great deal of that energy could be converted to power things with.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - "may be the total energy output by a human " No.  Please actually read the link provided, especially the last entry. While it's true that resting metabolism for an adult is typically about 100 watts, it's also about the average power which can be provided to a load by a person. The two states, resting and exercising, are quite different.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I did. That link's a little unclear to me. It seems to imply the total energy output is 100W; I can't see where it says that this is the rate of *working* of a human being, e.g. on a treadmill. There's the 30W example given churning ice cream, but this isn't an activity that is kept up for long periods.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - From the last entry - "The typical average continuous power that can be generated by pedaling is about one-sixth horsepower or 125 watts, more or less". That's power delivered to a mechanical load.

Comment: Typically an adult male is recommended to consume 2500 kilocalories = $10^7$ J per day. This corresponds to a power of a little over 100W. If you have done an absolute beast of a day of exercise, you might need to consume 5000 kilocalories - a factor of two. (Royal Marine Commandos in training get around 4000 calories a day.)

Answer (score 0):

Some idea of how wildly ambitious these claims are can be gleaned from a [BBC TV programme](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00p8469) that was broadcast about six years ago. In this show, they put a family of four in a house for a day and powered it through pedal power; they needed scores of cyclists. The show is no longer available directly from the BBC, but [this clip](https://youtu.be/C93cL_zDVIM) gives you some idea.

Alternatively, in [this video](https://youtu.be/S4O5voOCqAQ) an Olympic track cyclist nearly manages to toast a slice of bread.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how silly this is let's say you like to eat hot food (at least, hot enough not to die of food poisoning assuming you eat meat, and you cook it with a microwave which consumes 1,000 watts, which you run for ten minutes a day (three meals, three minutes per meal).  I'm assuming that a microwave is the most efficient practical way of cooking food: certainly they are hugely more efficient than electric ovens.

When you are not cooking or pedalling you use no power: when it's dark you sleep and you have thick clothes so you need no heating.

Microwave energy: $1,000\textrm{W}\times 600\textrm{s} = 600,000\textrm{J}$.

Bicycle energy: $100\textrm{W}\times 3,600\textrm{s} = 360,000\textrm{J}$.

Shortfall: $240,000\textrm{J}$.

And this is a single, relatively low-energy task: cycling for an hour a day provides *nowhere near* enough energy to run a modern household.

Comment: Your bike produced 60% of the needed energy. That's hardly _silly_. If you pedal a bit harder (e.g., 150W) and a bit longer (e.g., 4000s)  you get your 10 minutes of microwave energy. I think you just proved the opposite of what you intended.

Comment: @OwenBoyle - You really should try exercising enough to produce 150 watts for an hour. 100 watts is pretty much an upper limit for long-term work by a fit adult male. 150 watts is not "a bit harder" - it's virtually impossible. Unless you're an Olympic athlete in peak condition, perhaps. And doing it day after day would be no fun at all.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Well, [Wikipedia reckons 200W for an in-shape cyclist|https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-powered_transport] (are we supposed to do this without breaking sweat?) However, would you accept that 120W is within the bounds of possibility? And that you could keep it up for 5000s? Or simply cook for 6 minutes instead of 10? The point I'm making is that the output falls in the ball-park of the requirement and is very far from *silly*.

Comment: @OwenBoyle My point was that cycling for an hour fails to provide enough energy to do a single, relatively low-power thing: given that you may also want to heat or cool your house, use less efficient forms of cooker, consume hot drinks, wash in hot water, run lights, wash clothes, run computers and networking equipment &c &c it simply fails dismally.  Sorry, I thought that was obvious but clearly not.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast A really good amateur cyclist can output almost 350W for an hour. An olympic standard athelete will manage more than 400W. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30359/what-power-did-alex-dowsett-put-out-during-his-hour-record  Either way, it still isn't enough to power a house.

Comment: The "traditional" use of this technology is to bring just a few of the modern conveniences (like some night-time lighting and radio) to an off-the-grid living arrangement. The cooking and hot water and so on are usually provided by burning some kind of fuel. It becomes much more tractable if understood that way, but of course that's not "power[ing]  your home" for most people.

Comment: @RobJeffries They can ... with a very significant airflow to provide cooling, which will need to be provided using a large, power-hungry fan, if you don't want to kill them.

Comment: @tfb Oh sorry... I thought you were just talking about running a microwave for 10 minutes, which clearly is _not_ silly. You were actually talking about the original question, which was about a whole house. Obviously, that's not going to work... Your added sentence clarifies immensely :-)