# Can a gym be built to supply electricity to homes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, power, estimation

A moving magnet induces a current in a conductor, then shouldn't we be able to generate electricity through manual labour?

I was thinking about building a gym that used magnets as weights. People would lift the magnets up and down creating a change in flux generating current.

For example; the exercise bikes and the rowing machines would definitely be able to produce a current due to their rotating discs. Also, machines like a squat stand can be turned into a generator because the weight can be turned into a magnet. The key idea is that any machine that can move can turn into a generator to produce electricity for homes.

There should be many gyms spread out along the city like mini power stations. The electricity generated doesn't have to be used straight away but can also be stored in a battery for later use. I am wondering if there will be enough electricity generated to supply homes (if not all homes then a street or two).

Comment: I dont know if you have seen this or not but in Brazil they use inmates on stationary bikes to generate electricity.  - http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/brazil-prisoners-shorter-sentences-riding-exercise-bikes-tied-generators-article-1.1106336

Comment: It takes 5-10 hours for a person to generate a kWh. It costs more to feed them than the electricity generated. It's just punishment, not economics @ed.hank

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean.  I understand now.

Comment: That's just a more humane (maybe) variant of the [Matrix nonsense.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/is-the-basic-premise-of-humans-as-a-power-source-in-the-matrix-reasonable)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Presumably you're talking about [Black Mirror S01E02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_Million_Merits)?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Never heard of that, and I fail to make a connection. I was just disrespectful to the idea of using humans for power generation, an idea which is underlying the Matrix movies.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider (via wikipedia) "In this world, everyone must cycle on exercise bikes in order to power their surroundings and generate currency called Merits", much as the question suggests. Does that count as 'using humans for power generation'?

Comment: Very similar question; http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269747/how-feasible-is-it-to-power-your-home-with-a-bicycle/269823#269823

Comment: Using (simple) magnets for weight wouldn't work well.  The force between magnets depends on r^2, so you'd need a lot of force to move them the first little bit, then progressively very much less.  You could perhaps develop the electromagnetic equivalent of Nautilus machines, but they'd be expensive, and free weights are pretty cheap.

Comment: I would suggest that before trying to supply electricity to other homes it should try supplying electricity to itself... and it won't have much if any left over.

Comment: There is no need to re-engineer generators, you plug the rotating axis to an industry made generator and you're done with efficiency concerns. The problem here is about global thermodynamics. Rob Jeffries comment is spot on. Though if the concept is applied it could have a positive effect on how strong the people commit to their workout. Just don't tell them it's close to useless in fact.

Comment: This question makes me sad. Didn't you try the toaster-bike at the local scientific exploratory center?

Comment: @Michael's right.  Treadmills use so much that they would take everything you could make. I've just looked up one that's supposed to be more efficient than previous designs and the motor is rated at 8HP.  so if someone is sprinting and the machine draws that full ~6kW, it would take something like 20-30 bikes to power one treadmill.

Comment: But on the other hand [you can actually buy machines that do](http://www.technogym.com/gb/line/artis) (in addition to the machines that power their own interfaces, which some rowing machines and bikes have done for decades)

Comment: There might be some places on Earth where homes don't require that much power and you could get a group of people to provide all the power a home or street might need. But I, for one, live in a very cold (at times) climate. The amount of heat energy that my home loses to the outside environment in one day is more than I could generate if I spent literally all of my time working out at the gym for a week. That's just heating my home. Honestly, it'd be more efficient to just burn half my food in the middle of the house.

Comment: @Jim Well, you'd get just as much heat from working out at home (regardless of whether you convert that to electricity or not) as you'd get from burning the food. It'd just be a lot more work for you :P However, if you excercised *outside* of your home, you'd be entirely right - burning the food would be much more efficient for power generation.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The maximum continuous power that can be generated for an hour by a fairly fit person on an efficient machine like an exercise bike or rowing machine is $\sim 200$ W (olympic-standard track cyclists might manage 400 W).

Let's say that a gym is occupied at any time by 10 people who are doing this kind of intense exercise. Then you might just be producing enough electricity to boil a kettle (kettles are 2-3 kW) and keep the lights on in the gym. Unfortunately there are another 10 people in the showers who have just consumed more electricity than they generated (typical electric shower consumes 8kW, so a 2 minute shower needs 960 kJ = 200W $\times$ 80 minutes).

Does that answer the question?

However, it might be an interesting gimmick to allow people to charge up their phones or other personal devices using the electricity that they personally generate. That would probably be feasible with the right adaptors and transformers.

Comment: Its quite common to supply the exercise bike's electronics directly from generated electricity. And since some have USB ports it might already be possible to charge your phone, though I haven't personally seen such a feature yet.

Comment: To get some idea of what it takes to run a toaster as a cyclist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4O5voOCqAQ

Comment: NPR's youtube series covers it well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbUxt2x4InE and a more hilarious depiction of the question on the Grand Tour Ep 9, where they try to charge a car with a gym https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01J94A5GQ

Comment: A common gimmick for exercise bicycles is to have them power a television or similar device, as a way to motivate people to exercise.

Comment: @Emil I have tried charging my phone solely on a stationary bike it will light up my phones charging screen but I could not get any noticeable charge increase.

Comment: I assume you mean 200 W of mechanical work; I think that people generate more-or-less 1 KW of heat, don't they.

Comment: It's quite common in airports to see places where you can pedal to charge your phone

Comment: I think 200W is very generous for someone who is "fairly fit".

Comment: I must be fitter than fairly fit then. @whatsisname

Comment: @ChrisW No, they generate about 200W passively. The 200W in my answer is additional mechanical work.

Comment: The phone charge stuff by cycling already exists at train stations and airports.

Comment: @tpg2114 Typically, for those, the TV is powered by the mains, and a relay is switched on when you are producing enough power to turn the TV on.

Comment: @emil my gym has exactly this.  I frequently show up to the gym with a dead or dying phone, use the bike to charge my phone for about 45 minutes, and then unplug it and head upstairs to lift some free weights

Comment: DC-DC and AC-DC power supplies are small, cheap, and efficient.  (Easily over 90% for a switching power supply to supply a constant charging voltage / current from a varying input).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter

Answer (score 14):

Yes, these exist. There's one here in Portland, OR, USA called [The Green Microgym](http://www.thegreenmicrogym.com/). But it doesn't generate much energy. People wildly overestimate how much energy a human can produce.

[They claim to "*have generated 20% of our own electricity*" but it is done by "*combining human and solar power*"](http://www.thegreenmicrogym.com/the-story-of-the-green-microgym/green-advantage/). They claim to use "*Energy-producing cardio equipment (ellipticals and stationary bikes)*". I don't have any numbers for how much of that 20% is human power and how much is solar, but [Rob Jeffries already covered what a human is capable of](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/305632/52514): about 200 W.

If all 150 members exercised a very generous 1 hour a day producing 200 Wh each, and all that energy was turned into electricity with no loses, that's a maximum energy output of 30 kWh. To put that in perspective, [a refrigerator uses about 1.5 kWh per day](https://www.energystar.gov/index.cfm?fuseaction=refrig.calculator&model=&which=4&rate=0.1210&rconfig=Bottom+Freezer&screen=4&3aValue=1&manu=2011-2015&tvol=21.5-24.4+Cubic+Feet&submit.x=90&submit.y=24). So 150 people exercising an hour a day at peak capacity with perfect conversion to electricity can power about 20 fridges or about 0.133 fridges per person. That's an ideal scenario.

Most of the gym's efforts go into reducing electricity use and waste rather than generation claiming to have reduced their electricity use by 85% compared to normal gyms (per square foot).

---

There have been claims of generating electricity using human power before. This is entirely possible, but they generally wildly overstate how much power can be generated.

The most recent I've seen is the claim that ["60 Minutes On This Bicycle Can Power Your Home For 24 Hours"](http://waldenlabs.com/free-electric-bicycle-can-power-your-home/). This is nonsense. Note the total lack of details about the device in the article or video, they only talk about its potential.

As Rob said, the average person will put out about 200 [Wh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowatt_hour) in 60 minutes. A single [LED bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_lamp#Comparison_table) uses about 10 W or 240 Wh per day.

So, maybe if you live in a shack with one light the claim is true. More realistically, it could be used to charge a phone or laptop or power a radio.

Comment: This "combining human and solar power" looks like the joke with the special clam dish which is 50% clam and 50% pork, but it later turns out they meant one clam per one pig.

Comment: "maximum power output of 30 kWh": That's an energy output.

Comment: If a fridge eats up 1.5 kWh/day, it is (not just environmentally, but also purely economically) worth scrapping it and buying a new one with one third of this consumption; it pays off within 10 years on electricity.

Comment: I recall many years ago NPR did a story about this, or some similar gym. One of the gym patrons interviewed said that she had strong environmental beliefs that led her to use this gym in order to get in shape for her upcoming trip to Hawaii. Because of course there is nothing better for the planet than saving on a few pennies worth of power generation in exchange for setting on fire a few hundred bucks in aviation fuel.

Comment: After researching The Green Micro Gym, in an interview with the founder, it seems like the experience is less about creating electricity than it is about saving energy. He stated that after researching other gyms both large and small, his gyms saved on average about 85% more energy because while the gym is not being used, it is not using electricity. So rather than producing excess electricity to make money or power external systems, the ethos is directed toward saving energy by producing only what is needed for the current workout (lights and such). https://youtu.be/2WmsC9VhahU?t=2m13s

Comment: @dominecf The expected energy use of a fridge depends on size, but [1.5 kWh/day is the efficiency standard for the US](http://michaelbluejay.com/electricity/refrigerators2.html#sources). Its not the highest bar, but it certainly isn't a junker. To put it in perspective, that's what it takes to boil 2 L of water or run a 60W light bulb for a day or less than running many desktop PCs.

Answer (score 2):

As answered above no not electricity, but usable force has been done.

Treadmills originated as a corn mill powered by prisoners. They would stand on a large cylinder and turn it grinding corn.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a project in Paris: the [Paris Navigating Gym](https://vivre.paris/une-salle-de-gym-flottante-bientot-sur-la-seine/) (link in French). As mentioned in the project, the power of the cyclists is the only one used to move the boat.

Which, in the light of other answers, is hardly possible.

Answer (score 1):

There was a BBC program called 'The Human Power Station' that measured this. One hundred cyclists at full pelt just about managed to deliver the power needed for an electric shower... so a gym with a few people gently exercising on treadmills probably won't even keep the gym's lights on let alone export power to any other premises. There's a link here http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00p8469 but it's not currently available to view...

Answer (score -2):

The Grand Tour just did this. (the guys from old Top Gear) 
They tied all the gym equiment to generators, and probably maxed it out with hired people, and after 8 hours of lots of people working out 
 **they charged a GeeWiz electric car to about 30%, so it only went 20 miles.**

In conclusion, it's not a lot of energy. It would be enough to charge your phone while you're working out, but you need to invest a lot in the generating equipment which costs a lot more than the normal stuff. So it's not a good investment for a gym.

Comment: The Top Gear guys are notoriously against anything "economy". Assume any "tests" they do are opinion and theater, not science. This might be a good answer, but it needs a better source. (I'm sorry your first answer gets a downvote.)

Comment: Even so, the quantity of energy they generated seems to correlate with the quantity speculated by other answers here.